# UITableViewController didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

How can I reference the cell object that was clicked inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method?

I have a UISplitViewController, and in the MasterView I have a table, with cells where cell.tag = a primary key from a sqlite database (i.e. table is populated from db). I'm able to capture the click event in the above method, but I can't see how I can pass the cell object in, or how I can otherwise reference it to get at cell.tag. Ultimately, the goal is to pass that id to the detail view via the Master/Detail delegate, and then load data into the DetailView based on the id that comes in from the Master.

Any tips are appreciated!

Edit:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Detail", @"Detail");
    Entry *entry = [self.entries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",entry.title]];
    cell.tag = entry.entryID;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you already have an array of entries, you can also write as follows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Entry *entry = [self.entries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

I think this is preferred way than cellForRowAtIndexPath: because

- you can get the whole entry object, not only the ID.
- you can use non-integer ID like string.
- you don't depend on table or cell (decoupling).

Comment: Yes, this is even better. I assumed I had to pass I'd and query the db again, but if I can just pass the whole entry object that's best case scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Note how asking the table for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns a cell, whereas asking the controller for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` runs the delegate method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method [cellForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) to get the UITableViewCell from the NSIndexPath.

Comment: That's actually where I'm populating the cell attribute I'm interested in. See edit above. Are you saying I can call that method from inside of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 0):

You can it by save all id in NSMutableArray and then pass in by this method in an other class..

`classInstanceName.IntVariableName=[[taskIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]`